# Clients in trusted doman unable to see masterpage changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I am using 2013 Enterprise. I have a single web app in a single zone. I have users in a Client AD forest and users in a Corporate AD Forest. There is a 2 way forest level trust between domains.

I added 3 lines of JavaScript (it hides some page elements) to the bottom of my masterpage (A copy of it). I checked it in and published a major version. I set it as the default master page. I did this in Designer.

I can see the changes have taken affect when I login with my user account. I can see the script on the page when I view the source. When I log in as a user in the Client AD forest the changes aren't seen.

Any ideas?? Any debugging tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common cause of this I've found is that the new master page update is not checked in **and** approved in the master page gallery.

Ensure you've checked the file in by selecting the file (check the checkbox next to it in the list view) and clicking 'Check In' in the ribbon, or by selecting Check in from the edit control block (ECB - the dropdown next to list items in SharePoint)

Make sure the file is approved by selecting the file and then using the "Approve/Reject" option in the ribbon or in the ECB.

Comment: So the issue was that the user did not have edit permissions on the Master Pages and Page Layouts library. Apparently Read isn't enough! The solution was found [here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/198237.aspx)

Comment: @Rich that seems pretty suspicious... users in my environment do NOT have edit permission in the master page gallery (nor would I want them to) and they can still see changes and custom master pages just fine... If you would like to see why **this is a terrible idea**, navigate to the master page gallery as any old user (now that you've given them edit permission) and edit the master page... this may also be worth a read: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60699/user-with-full-control-permission-is-getting-access-denied-message

Comment: I agree it sounds iffy. Everything else was done correctly regarding SuperCache Reader/User and the publishing of masterpages. I will take off the edit for everyone and run some test to see what shows up in the logs. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I published a major version. I had been doing this in Designer, or so I thought, but apparently it wasn't working. I published a major version through the ribbon on the Master Pages Library instead, deleted the Everyone group with edit rights from the library and now I'm able to see the changes.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I didn't think of the SPD viewpoint (publish major version) piece - I'm going to try and reach out to the O365 forum folks and see if I can have that other answer taken down somehow