# Users with edit permission on list unable to save changes

Tags: permissions, access-denied, edit-form

I am the site owner and am able to make any changes but I have two other users who have edit access who receive an error message "Access Denied, You Do Not Have Permission to Perform This Action or Access this Resource." if they try to stop editing a list.  They can type changes into fields but not save.

I have checked their permissions by accessing the settings for the form which shows edit permission. I have also checked the site permissions which also shows as edit.

I don't have InfoPath or superuser access so wondered if I had made an error in editing the form at some point which would have inadvertently removed other user edit access.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are tricky. It depends on whether there is inheritance sometimes. What often helps me is to remove the person's access entirely and then reissue it several minutes later. I also make sure that I delete unique permissions to ensure there are no inheritance issues.

Check out this related site: [User with Full Control Permission is getting Access Denied Message](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60699/user-with-full-control-permission-is-getting-access-denied-message?rq=1)